# What is a way to ship thousands of tons of gases to another planet at one time?

Tags: space-travel, travel

So I've already got these huge pumps that collect all of the air "pollution" from factories. They harvest all the gases and compact it into dirigible balloons.

The point of all this is to send CO<sub>2</sub> and methane to other planets to begin creating a feasible atmosphere to begin to support low-energy plants, like bamboo.

How would I ship the gases to a nearby planet or system? Would this even work for creating an atmosphere?

**EDIT:**

My ideas for transportation are an ion particle accelerator like L<sub>3</sub> makes. slow, but utterly efficient.  I guess the biggest problem is it would be super expensive if I have to send small payloads but I can't quite figure out how to send larger amounts without creating multiple craft for each planetary mass. I need it to work in different situations

Comment: At the moment, I'm voting to close this as "opinion based" - *the best* way is not definable in an objective view. I think there is a question to be had here - if you can clean it up, please [edit] to do so.

Comment: I don't think this idea is going to prove to be feasible, but to get a good answer you need to at the very least specify the technology level you have available, and explain the criteria by which answers should be rated..

Comment: We would need more information to answer this.  For example, accelerating tons of material towards another planet requires lots and lots of energy, gas liquid or solid.  What sort of technology are we looking at for this transport effort?

Comment: BTW we can harvest the waste gasses from the smog as fuel if we need to. modern tech levels.

Comment: A lot of times, you can scientifically determine the best way and this is not opinion based...

Comment: You have two problems - 1) How to deal with pollution.  2)  How to build a atmosphere on a dead rock.  I don't think they dovetail as one might hope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compress the gas and keep it cool, just like liquid natural gas is transported on Earth's oceans via an [LNG carrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LNG_carrier). The actual spaceflight and balloon-spaceship interface is dependent on your tech level and setting.

But considering the volume of gas in an atmosphere, adding a few thousand tons might not have such a big impact.